# Mac OSX GLFW Fullscreen Crash

Tags: glfw, lwjgl3

Whenever I run my code to make a fullscreen GLFW window, it crashes.

Here is the code:

```
package ext.tpz.test;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (glfwInit() == false) {
            System.out.println("GLFW failed to init.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        long fullscreen = 0;
        if(args.length >= 1) {
            if (args[0].equals("-fullscreen")) {
                fullscreen = 1;
            }
        }
        long win = glfwCreateWindow(640,480, "Test", fullscreen, 0);


        glfwShowWindow(win);
        while(glfwWindowShouldClose(win) == false ) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        glfwTerminate();
    }
}
```

Here is the crash report:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000012dd11841, pid=13565, tid=1811
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [libglfw.dylib+0x9841]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /Users/a677c774/IdeaProjects/LWJGL 3 Tests/hs_err_pid13565.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:  http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you set the `fullscreen` variable to 1, instead this variable should be set to a monitor value.

To retrieve the default monitor's value you can call glfw's method `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()`.

This should solve the main issue, besides of that I have also added the context creation, window update and window clearing function calls.

You can find a documentation on how to use glfw at
http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        System.out.println("Failed to initialize GLFW.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    long fullscreen = NULL;
    if(args.length >= 1) {
        if (args[0].equals("-fullscreen")) {
            fullscreen = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
        }
    }

    long window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", fullscreen, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        System.out.println("Failed to create the window.");
        glfwTerminate();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities(); 

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Please describe what changed from what the user posted, how you fixed it and how you discovered the issue. This will make a much better answer.

Comment: Alexandre, I did not discover this, it is just my default way of working, therefore I only gave a summary about the changes and why it should be changed.
Thank you for the advice on commenting though.

Comment: Ah, then perhaps you should change "This should solve your problem. " by something like "I'm not sure exactly how to fix your specific issue, but here is the way I do what you're attempting with lwjgl and glfw. " That would be a bit more exact :)

Comment: Not really, the problem was that he set the value of `fullscreen` to 1 but it is supposed to be assigned to a monitor value, which preferably is the default monitor, the way to get the default monitor value is `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();`. Therefore the question is solved.
I do know how to fix it but this is not a discovery, this is just how I found it in the glfw documentation when I started using glfw.

Comment: " the problem was that he set the value of fullscreen to 1 but it is supposed to be assigned to a monitor value, which preferably is the default monitor, the way to get the default monitor value is glfwGetPrimaryMonit‌​or(); [...] I found it in the glfw documentation" that's just the kind explanation that is expected to be seen before the chunk of code in the answer :)

Comment: Oh okay, well again, thank you for the advice on commenting.
This is my first day to really try and help out on this page.
I really appreciate the fact that you are showing me the right way of commenting on a question :)

Comment: You can edit your answer to put that in :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44098/discussion-between-tripl3fac3-and-alexandre-vaillancourt).